# Index out of range , Python?

Tags: python

My program is supposed to auto-fill (like ms paint) a text file. I cannot figure out why this is giving me an index out of range.

Also my fill function must be recursive, and making the call to neighboring cells in the following order: above,right,below, and left. Better or more efficient ways to do this please let me know(that's if i'm even doing what I want it to be doing).

Comment: Please show us full stacktrace!

Comment: This is surely unrelated to your exception, but `input(print("..."))` doesn't do what you want. It prints the prompt, but then also prints `None` as well. You don't need to use `print` in that context, `input` prints its argument already.

Comment: @ozgur is that what your looking for?

Comment: @Blckknght honestly I was wondering where the None would randomly come from, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`[int(row)][int(col)]` doesn't work as you expect.

It creates a list with one element, which is `int(row)` and then tries to access its `int(col)` element. Actually this line will raise an exception every time `int(col)` is `> 0`.

Instead, you should use a tuple:

```
p = int(row), int(col)
```

but keep in mind that it is immutable, so you can't change it directly later:

```
p = int(row), int(col)
p[0] = 3
>> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Though you can reassign a new tuple:

```
p = int(row), int(col)
p = 3, int(col)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Ive change it to a tuple , now its giving me a list index out of range at ,    if board[pos[0]][pos[1]+1] == ' ':

Comment: It is the same error for the same reason,  so apply the same solution  :)